# End of line error appearing in the end of the conditional statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying out some conditional statements but I am getting indentation error at the end of the statement. I am trying to delete the last condition but the error appear again. How to resolve this.

```
import numpy as np
new_sobel = np.random.randint(100, size=(100,100))
theta= np.random.randint(10, size=(100,100))


MM, NN = new_sobel.shape
Z = np.zeros((MM,NN), dtype=np.int32)
angle = theta * 180. / np.pi
angle[angle < 0] += 180

for i in range(1,MM-1):
    for j in range(1,NN-1):
        try:
            q=255;
            r=255;
            if (0 <= angle[i,j] < 22.5) or (157.5 <= angle[i,j] <= 180):
                        q = new_sobel[i, j+1]
                        r = new_sobel[i, j-1]
                    
            elif (22.5 <= angle[i,j] < 67.5):
                        q = new_sobel[i+1, j-1]
                        r = new_sobel[i-1, j+1]
                    
            elif (67.5 <= angle[i,j] < 112.5):
                        q = new_sobel[i+1, j]
                        r = new_sobel[i-1, j]
                    
            elif (112.5 <= angle[i,j] < 157.5):
                        q = new_sobel[i-1, j-1]
                        r = new_sobel[i+1, j+1]
        
            if (new_sobel[i,j] >= q) and (new_sobel[i,j] >= r):
                        Z[i,j] = new_sobel[i,j]
            else:
                        Z[i,j] = 0
```

Comment: I think you need an ```except:``` with every ```try:``` statement.

Comment: What is the functionality of except

Comment: The code you put after except is called if the try block encounters an exception. You can also specify how to catch a specific exception. [Here's more information](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

`except` is missing from your `try` block as stated by @Lcj
Because it expected `except` at the end of `try` block.

Also, to answer your comment on functionality of except:

It can be used whenever you have some idea of where and how your code can break or you know those usecases where it won't work, so you define try-except block and put your that part of code inside `try` block and what you need to do as soon as your code break is what you put inside the `except` block.

Often, it is useful for logging errors use to debug code.

For ex.
Toy example :

```
try :   
    for i in range(0, 10):
        print(c/i)  # c can be any constant
except :
    print("ZeroDivisonError : not possible to divide any number by zero !") # can do anything here once it breaks and comes to this section
```

So, the loop variable "i" at the start only reaches 0 and as we know c/0 can't be defined and so we print the error along with any other info.